# How to create fixed size(height and width) 2d barcode using itext API in JAVA?

Tags: java, pdf, java-8, itext, barcode

I am trying to create a fixed size(height and width) 2d barcode in java using itext api, but barcode size is changing based on length of code we set to barcode object. More the length of code we set, longer the barcode is generated. please help.

```
 BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
 barcode.setCode("BarcodePDF417 barcode");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is A Blank PDF417 BarCode with NO Data

[image]

Here is the minimal test data just a small one line phrase

[image]

Here is a longer single line of text
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

[image]

And "PDF417 is a stacked linear barcode symbol format used in a variety of applications, primarily transport, identification cards, and inventory management."
produces [image]

Clearly as you add more content the size needs to increase in steps.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417 where it explains how the barcode needs to be much longer for PDF417 characters than say a QR type barcode and can thus never be "fixed" height for a fixed width unless code length is always the same. Also consider distance to scanner also dictates the minimum working area where for a QR code the size ratio is recommended as 1/10 scanner distance but I dont know how that is guaged for PDF417 as it is usually scanned in contact thus the key is the minimum size of x (1) and y (usually 3) needed to achieve a reliable result.

For comparisons against your own output you can use an online creator such as
https://bcgen.com/pdf417-barcode-creator.html